# Swift - programmatically set UIScrollView width to 100%

Tags: swift, size, scrollview, programmatically-created

In the designer I added a Scrollview, I made it have a scrollbar with this code:

```
svDetails.contentSize = CGSizeMake(360, 400);
```

However I want it to be 100% of the phone width. (leave the width unchanged).

Because right now it fits perfectly on iPhone 4s,5 and 5s but doesn't look quite right on the iPhone 6,6+ (scrollview is to small)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
svDetails.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dharmesh Kheni' solution from above in

**Swift 3:**

```
svDetails.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: This is minor, but it's also bad form to use `self.` when you don't have to in swift.